# IoGetDeviceProperly causes BSOD

Tags: windows, driver, bsod, hardware-id

I have written a filter driver for hard disks in Windows ( like DiskPerf of DDK ) and I need to get some information about device which my driver is attached to it, for example HardWareID.
I use IoGetDeviceProperly inside my IRP_MJ_READ function. But this method causes BSOD and BSOD says problem is "IRQL_NO_LESS_OR_EQUAL". MSDN says DispatchRead and IoGetDeviceProperly, both run at PASSIVE_LEVEL.
What is wrong?
How can I get information about device that driver is attached to it?

Comment: They don't run at passive, they only work correctly at passive.  Paging I/O requests run at apc level, you'll have to avoid those.

Answer (score 0):

The DispatchRead routine can be called at IRQL = APC_LEVEL.

See [Dispatch Routines and IRQLs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/dispatch-routines-and-irqls)

Call IoGetDeviceProperty and save device information in DispatchCreate and Use it in DispatchRead.